# Multi-Filtering a collection of products

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to create multi-filters for my collections.

For example: In the first filter Drop Down list customers can pick MARVEL and in the second one I want them to see only MARVEL characters.

My questions are:

1. Which code do I need to write to get the value of the first drop down list?
2. Is it possible to generate a list of all products containing the tags MARVEL + another tag?

(I'm using the free theme 'Venture' if that helps somehow)

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
    <div class="collection-sort">
  <label for="SortTags" class="collection-sort__label">Universe</label>
  <select name="SortTags" id="SortTags" class="collection-sort__input">
    {% if collection.handle %}
      <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ 'collections.sorting.all_of_collection' | t }}</option>
    {% elsif collection.current_type %}
      <option value="{{ collection.current_type | url_for_type }}">{{ 'collections.sorting.all_of_collection' | t }}</option>
    {% elsif collection.current_vendor %}
      <option value="{{ collection.current_vendor | url_for_vendor }}">{{ 'collections.sorting.all_of_collection' | t }}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% assign tags = 'MARVEL,DC,Games,Movies,TV' | split: ',' %}
    var test;
    {% for tag in tags%}
      <option value="/collections/{% if collection.handle != blank %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handleize }}"{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected="selcted"{% endif %}>{{ tag }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You can stack tags with `+`. So for example `marvel+dc+comics` etc.. This will return products that have those 3 tags only. You have the object 'current_tags` that returns all the tags on the current page, so that way you can get all of them.

Comment: This could work but products also have irrelevant tags i don't want to show. Is it possible to show only tags like "DC_Batman" or "MARVEL_Ironman" to do that i will have to get the value used in the first drop down list. also is it possible to show only what's coming after the "MARVEL_"?